# Get class namespace and name from class reference, without changing my classes

Tags: php, reference, classname

In php you often check if the object you get is of the correct type. If not you throw an exception with a message like this:

```
use My\Class\MyClass

...

if (!$object instanceof MyClass) {
    throw new Exception(
        sprintf(
            "object must be of type '%s'", 
            'My\Class\MyClass'
        )
    );
}
```

Right now I pass the full namespace and the name of the class in a string to `sprintf`.

How can I get this from the class reference so that i can do something like this

```
sprintf("object must be of type '%s'", MyClass::getName())
```

**EDIT:**

I would like to achieve this for all classes without adding new methods. So it should be a solution using some existing method or one of the php __ MAGIC__ methods.

Comment: As of php5.6 you can simply use `MyClass::class`.

Comment: @Maerlyn If you post that as an answer you get the reward :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of php 5.5 there's a magic constant that gives you the FQCN of any class. You can use it like this:

```
namespace My\Long\Namespace\Foo\Bar;

MyClass::class;
// will return "My\Long\Namespace\Foo\Bar\MyClass"
```

It's documented on the [new features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) page.

Comment: Cool. My phpstorm also knew the feature, it recognized the variable :)

Comment: Be careful, though: 5.6 is still very new and barely used in the wild. Unless you roll your own servers, it's doubtful you can use its new features.

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace test;

class a {

    public function getname()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

And:

```
$a = new a();
echo $a->getname(); //
```

**Outputs**

```
test\a
```

Static method works same way:

```
public static function getname()
{
    return __CLASS__;
}

...

a::getname(); // test\a
```

You can also get only namespace with `__NAMESPACE__`

**Update:**
you can you `ReflectionClass` for same thing:

```
$a = new a();

$r = new \ReflectionClass($a);
echo $r->getName(); // test\a
```

you can create `ClassHelper` class to have it for using anywhere you need it easily:

```
class ClassHelper
{
    public static function getFullQualifiedName($object)
    {
        $rc = new \ReflectionClass($object);
        return $rc->getName();
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
echo ClassHelper::getFullQualifiedName($a); // test\a
```

**Finnaly:** if you use php 5.6 and above (for future), you can work with `class` constant

```
echo a::class; // test\a
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I don't want to add a `getName` method to all my classes.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but those solutions are not what I was looking for. If you see @Maerlyn his comment you see there is an easier way. He gave me what I was looking for.

Comment: I was gonna post it too but, first posting my answer, because `MyClass::class` only work for php 5.6 and above, but anyway I was gonna include it too